# LibreOffice calc; is it possible to automatically make cells coloured according to the HTML code entered into them?

Tags: colors, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, cells

I am creating a LibreOffice calc spreadsheet designed to be basically be a customized version of the table entitled "Default element colors, by atomic number:" on this page http://jmol.sourceforge.net/jscolors/. Part of this is I'd like to be able to make certain cells formatted so that they colour their backgrounds according to the HTML code entered into them (e.g., if I enter FFFFFF into a cell it should become coloured white).

Comment: I don't know wether you can parse HTML inside a cell, but you can use *conditional formatting*.

Comment: It's very, very difficult. You could try to create a custom [palette](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Draw_Guide/Color_palette) that maps the Jmol RGB colors to certain names. Then, you could create a set of cell styles, one for each of the JMol colors (!). Finally, you could use the [STYLE()](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function) function to apply the cell style according to the cell content. Alternatively, you could define a conditional format rule for every color code to apply the according style...